# Cannot run gnome-session

Tags: rhel5, 64-bit, gnome

I'm having issues running an X Windows session on a RHEL5 64-bit server - whenever I execute the command "gnome-session &", the process goes into the background but nothing happens.  I have Exceed installed on my Windows machine which is running when I try to start the gnome-session.  I've tried just starting firefox by itself instead of the whole gnome session, but it doesn't work either.  Any suggestions?

BTW, here's the error message I get when I try to start firefox:

> firefox: Fatal IO error 104 (Connection reset by peer) on X server localhost:10.0.

Comment: Why are you trying to manually start gnome from the command-line rather than a graphical runlevel?

Comment: I don't know...I guess because that's the only way I know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was due to a corrupt .Xauthority file after my SSH session had timed out.  When I deleted the file, logged out and logged back in to SSH, a new .Xauthority file was created and after that I was able to start firefox and gnome-session.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried issuing the **startx** command?

You appear to be getting the firefox error as you are launching it without a supporting X session (in your questions, **gnome**) running.

That's the proper way to start gnome and it should start automatically, if it doesn't than running **startx** manually will launch the graphical client that is specified in your */etc/X11/xinit/Xclients* script file.

Check the **startx** manual page for more information:

```
man startx
```

That should explain how it works and where the default files are located.